# Android App Security issue: Username Password not encrypted for credential storage in Android API level 24 and above

Tags: android, security, encryption, password-encryption

Apologize for being light on detail in the earlier description of this issue. 
Here is the issue in more detail:

Our Android App failed a security scan as it is encrypting username and password and storing locally using The Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) encryption algorithm with ECB cipher. The Sonarcube reference states that we need to use Galois/Counter Mode (GCM) with no padding. However this is not working for API level 24 and above.

We are trying to resolve this using ...

Cipher.getInstance(“AES/GCM/NoPadding”);

... but no luck in API level 24 and above.Encryption is not hapenning.

**MORE DETAIL:**

We encrypt the userid and password with keystore during App Login, which works properly. However when we decrypt it in another part of the application, we get *AEADBadTagException.*

Here's the code for encryption (This works fine):

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void encryptText() {
    try {
        final byte[] encryptedText = encryptor
                .encryptText("MY_ALIAS",mPsd.toString());
    } catch (UnrecoverableEntryException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | KeyStoreException | IOException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException e) {
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | SignatureException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here's the encryptor class (This also appears to work fine):

```
public class EnCryptor {
private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";
private static final String ANDROID_KEY_STORE = "AndroidKeyStore";

private byte[] encryption;
private byte[] iv;

public EnCryptor() {
}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public byte[] encryptText(final String alias, final String textToEncrypt)
        throws UnrecoverableEntryException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException,
        NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException,
        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, SignatureException, BadPaddingException,
        IllegalBlockSizeException {

    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(alias));

    iv = cipher.getIV();
    encryption = cipher.doFinal(textToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().saveEncrypt(Base64.encodeToString(encryption, Base64.DEFAULT));
    SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().saveEncrypted_iv(Base64.encodeToString(iv, Base64.DEFAULT));
    return (encryption);

}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@NonNull
private SecretKey getSecretKey(final String alias) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {

    final KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator
            .getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
    keyGenerator.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias,
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
            .build());
    return keyGenerator.generateKey();
}
public byte[] getEncryption() {
    return encryption;
}
public byte[] getIv() {
    return iv;
}
}
```

However, when attempting to decrypt the password later in another part of the application we encounter the error.

Method call from Fragment:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private char[] decryptText() {
    try {
        String txt = decryptor.decryptData("MY_ALIAS",
                Base64.decode(SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getEncrypt(), Base64.DEFAULT),
                Base64.decode(SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getEncrypted_iv(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        return txt.toCharArray();
    } catch (UnrecoverableEntryException | NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            KeyStoreException | NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchProviderException |
            IOException | InvalidKeyException e) {
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "".toCharArray();
}
```

And here is the Decryptor class, that throws the exception

```
public class DeCryptor {

private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";
private static final String ANDROID_KEY_STORE = "AndroidKeyStore";
private KeyStore keyStore;
public DeCryptor() throws CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException,
        IOException {
    initKeyStore();
}
private void initKeyStore() throws KeyStoreException, CertificateException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
    keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
    try {
        keyStore.load(null);
    } catch (java.security.cert.CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public String decryptData(final String alias, final byte[] encryptedData, final byte[] encryptionIv)
        throws UnrecoverableEntryException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException,
        NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException,
        BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {

    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
    final GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, encryptionIv);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(alias), spec);
    return new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedData), "UTF-8");
}
private SecretKey getSecretKey(final String alias) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        UnrecoverableEntryException, KeyStoreException {
    return ((KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(alias, null)).getSecretKey();
}
}
```

This is where we encounter the ***AEADBadTagException.***

Comment: Try NOPADDING instead of NoPadding

Comment: @GabeSechan: Case is not relevant.

Comment: Please include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please remove the hold on this question as I have added more detail (sorry for the delay)

Answer (score 0):

Use below line for decrypting:

```
IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(encryptionIv)
```

Rather than

```
final GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, encryptionIv)
```